# Customizing mat-calendar component navbar of material angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Want to edit the properties of mat-calendar of a component.

tried using `::ng-deep` but changes reflecting in all other components to.

before:

[image]

expected output:

[image]

code:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-period-button{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Tried editing mat-calendar nav bar using `::ng-deep`
but effecting all other occurrences of mat-calendar in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `panelClass` will allow you to specify in which data pickers should mat-calendar-period-button be hidden

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="my-datepicker"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
::ng-deep .my-datepicker .mat-calendar-period-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker